# Ubuntu 16.04 lts freezes, even after upgrading kernel

Tags: kernel, 16.04, freeze

I installed Ubnuntu 16.04 LTS on my machine last week.
Few days after, it started freezing randomly.
I upgraded the kernel version to `4.5.0-040500-generic` after some search results suggested an upgrade as a fix.
For a day and half I did not experience that issue, but it started again today, freezing 3 times.
Anyway of rectifying this?

Comment: In my experience, random freezes are most often caused by hardware faults. Does memtest come out clean, for example?

Comment: In most cases this is related to video drivers.

Comment: @fkraiem I did not see option to run memtest when I restarted and pressed `SHIFT~.

Comment: @Pilot6 it freezes most times when I am downloading a large file or watching a video on YouTube. I am not certain if these are the reasons, but these are the frequent things I was doing each time it froze and this is so annoying.